# How to determine optimal control law

Tags: dynamical-systems, control-theory, optimal-control

I was given the state space equation, $\dot{x} = -2x + u$ and told to determine the optimal control law $u=-kx$ which minimizes the performance index

$$J = \int_{0}^{\infty} x^{2}\,dt.$$

My approach was to find the state feedback $k$. But since the value of $R$ (positive definite Hermitian) is not given. That means $R=0$. How do I determine the optimal control for this system where $R=0$?

Comment: @DMcMor Yes that's what I mean. Thank you. Please can you help out?

Comment: @DMcMor yes that's what i mean. Thank you. How do i proceed please?

Comment: I think what you're looking for is Pontryagin's Minimum Principle.

Comment: What will happen if you initially do not take $R=0$ and take the limit as it goes to zero?

Comment: Since R=0 you can minimize your J as you want. Use u=-kx then the solution will be $x(t)=e^{-(2+k)t}x_0$ put this solution in J which gives $J=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-(4+2k)t}x_0^2dt$. So J can be minimized as k gets large  so we can get zero cost if k approaches infinity which makes no sense. One must specify the upper bound of J.