# How to determine the optimal control law?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, optimization, control-theory, optimal-control, linear-control

> Given the differential equation
>
> $$\dot x = -2x + u$$
>
> determine the optimal control law $u = - kx$ that minimizes the performance index
>
> $$J = \int_0^{\infty} x^2 \, \mathrm d t$$

My approach was to find the state feedback $k$. But since the value of $R$ (positive semidefinite Hermitian) is not given, that means $R=0$. How do I determine the optimal control for this system where $R=0$?

Comment: I have edited your equations with MathJax.  I believe I have kept the correct syntax.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat yeah, thanks. Can you help me understand how to solve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine optimal control law](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2235886/how-to-determine-optimal-control-law)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the state feedback law $u = - \kappa \, x$, where $\kappa$ is to be determined, we obtain

$$\dot x =  -(\kappa + 2) \, x$$

Integrating,

$$x (t) = \exp \left( -(\kappa + 2) t \right) \, x_0$$

where $x_0$ is the initial condition. Hence,

$$\int_0^{\infty} \left( x (t) \right)^2 \, \mathrm d t = \cdots = \dfrac{x_0^2}{2 (\kappa + 2)}$$

where the integral converges if $\kappa > -2$. Note that there is no minimum, but

$$\lim_{\kappa \to \infty} \dfrac{x_0^2}{2 (\kappa + 2)} = 0$$